# combining different records into one row

Tags: sas

I am new to the SAS programming. I am cleaning several data and after merging them I got the following result

**id**    **col1**    **col2**   **col3**
1        a     .      .
1      .       b      .
1      .       .      c

How would I write a code to get the output below
**id**    **col1**    **col2**   **col3**
1      a       b      c

your inputs are greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

data newData;
    update oldData(obs=0)oldData;
    by id;
run;

I wrote this and it did work!!!